# awk: Escaping and quoting not working on string "...$"

Tags: shell, awk, escaping, quoting

Below is my sample data, in a file called 'tt':

```
"UDBPEM1 "."HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02$" 
"UDBPEM1 "."HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02$"
```

I want to replace "HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02$" with "HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02$_MIG"

Why does this awk command intended to do a substitution not work?

```
awk '/HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02\$/ {sub("'HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02\$'","'HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02\$_MIG'")} {print}' tt
```

EDIT: The awk command here is used to replace the object name picked from another file. $ can be anywhere in the name, but i want _mig to be at the end. My actual awk command which i use in my script is below:

```
awk '/"'${TAB_NAME}'"/{if (M==""){sub("'${TAB_NAME}'","'${TAB_NAME}_${TAB_EXT}'");M=1}}{print}'  filename
```

I have to use "" to expand awk to use shell variables and I just want to replace the first occurrence.

Comment: are you just adding _MIG on the end ?

Comment: yes I am just adding _MIG at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your awk line, the quotes were not correctly used. do

```
awk '{sub(/H....\$/, "replacement")}7' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed for this purpose and you don't need to replace the whole string just replacing `$` with `$_MG` is enough,

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^$]*\$)(.*)$/\1_MG\2/g' file
"UDBPEM1 "."HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02$_MG" 
"UDBPEM1 "."HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02$_MG"
```

**OR**

A simpler one,

```
$ sed 's/\$/$_MG/g' file
"UDBPEM1 "."HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02$_MG" 
"UDBPEM1 "."HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02$_MG"
```

Comment: if you put `$` in `[]`, you don't need `\\`

Comment: you mean i don't need to escape dollar sign in character class?

Comment: Thanks for reply Avinash and Kent. But I can't use sed as this awk command is part of larger loop which pciks name from a file use awk to find it in another file and replace it. awk command posted by me was not working with object name having $ in them.

Comment: @user3782578 it would be better if you edit your question a bit more according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/\$/,"$_MG")}1' file

sed 's/\$/$_MG/' file
```

When you wrote:

```
awk '...sub("'HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02\$'",...)...' file
```

The single quotes withing your `sub()` were causing your shell script to exit and re-enter awk the awk script specification so the `HISTOGRAMBIN_@@@@@002__UDBDI02\$` was actully being interpreted by shell first and THEN because you had the RE enclosed in double quotes instead of RE delimiters (`/`) the resulting string was being interpreted by awk twice, once when the script was read and then again when it was executed. So - you'd have had to escape that `$` at least 3 times before awk stood a chance of it still being escaped when the script was executed.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton for explaining my mistake with awk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,

I got my awk command working

```
awk '/'${TAB_NAME}'/ {if (M==""){sub(/'$TAB_NAME'/,"'${TAB_NAME}_${TAB_EXT}'");M=1}}{print}' tt
```

Thanks [kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent), [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) and [avinash-raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/) for help.